# Mockito void method how to inspect private variable?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to unit test a void method which gets data from  database, formats into map and passes onto another class.

I have mocked out the database call and returned my own data, and I want to inspect the map which has been formatted contains the right number of elements and keys in right locations.

I have tried playing around with argumentCaptor to do this but struggling to get my head round it.

Method to test:

```
public class MyClass {

@Autowired
private Dao dao;

@Autowired
private AnotherClass anotherClass;

public void format(String, Date) {  
    Map<Object,Object> map = getDataAndFormat(String, Date); 
    anotherClass.doSomething(map);    
}

private Map<Object, Object> getDataAndFormat(String, Date) {
    Map map;
    if (String.equals("A") {
        map = dao.getData(Date);
    }
    else {
        map = dao.getDataSomeThingElse(Date);
    }
}
```

}
Any help much appreciated

Thanks,

so: This is what I have so far:

```
@InjectMocks
@Autowired
//class to test
private MyClass myClass;

@Mock
Dao dao;

@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<String> argumentCaptor;

@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<Date> argumentCaptorB;
public void testFormat() 

{
    when(dao.getData(Matchers.any())).thenReturn(data());

   myClass.format("A",new Date());
}
```

So i want to use argument captors (but not entirely sure how to) to get the map from the format method call and inspect the returned map.  The code i currently have is hitting all my code but I can't assert on anything hence why i wanted to check the map contains what I expect it to.  Hope that makes sense

Comment: What id you try ?

Comment: _I have tried playing around with argumentCaptor to do this_ - care to show us your attempts and what issues they are creating?

Comment: Have you read the documentation, which has an example? https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.29/org/mockito/Mockito.html#15.

Comment: And you aren't just mocking `anotherClass` because?

Comment: added some more detail above, hope hat makes a little more sense now.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears that what you want to do is to confirm the contents of the map that is passed to `AnotherClass`.

If `AnotherClass` is an interface, you can create a mock instance of `AnotherClass` and inject it into your `MyClass`.  You can then verify that it has been called with your arguments of choice:

```
Mockito.verify(mockAnotherClass).doSomething(expectedMap);
```

Comment: Thanks this make sense but if I want to check the map passed into doSomething is of size three, how would I do this?

Comment: In this case, the argument you would pass into `doSomething` would be a `Matcher` that checks for a map of that size.